# How do developers typically use Docker with a Java Maven project and AWS EC2?

Tags: maven, docker, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, devops

I have a single Java application. We developed the application in Eclipse. It is a Maven project. We already have a system for launching our application to AWS EC2. It works but is rudimentary and we would like to learn about the more common and modern approaches other teams use to launch their Java Maven apps to EC2. We have heard of Docker and I researched the tool yesterday. I understand the basics of building an image, tagging it and pushing to either Docker Hub or Amazon's ECS service. I have also read through a few tutorials describing how to pull a Docker image into an EC2 instance. However, I don't know if this is what we are trying to do, given that I am a bit confused about the role Docker can play in our situation to help make our dev ops more robust and efficient.

Currently, we are building our Maven app in Eclipse. When the build completes, we run a second Java file that uses the AWS JDK for Java to

- launch an EC2 instance
- copy the.jar artifact from the build into this instance
- add the instance to a load balancer  and
- test the app

My understanding of how we can use Docker is as follows. We would Dockerize our application and push it to an online repository according to the steps in [this video.](http://www.deegeu.com/deploy-java-applications-using-docker/)
Then we would create an EC2 instance and pull the Docker image into this new instance according to the steps in [this tutorial.](https://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2015/11/11/running-docker-aws-ground-up/)
If this is the typical flow, then what is the purpose of using Docker here? What is the added benefit, when we are currently ...

- creating the instance,
- deploying the app directly to the instance and also
- testing the running app

all using a simple single Java file and functions from the AWS SDK for Java?

Comment: I noticed Nathaniel's response here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635055/how-do-developers-typically-use-docker-with-a-java-maven-project-and-aws-ec2 suggests Docker is extraneous when a .jar is already very portable.

Answer (score 3):

@GNG what are your objectives for containerization?

Amazon ECS is the best method if you want to operate in only AWS environment.
Docker is effective in hybrid environments i.e., on physical servers and VMs.

Comment: Thank you. My objective is to have an easily maintainable and reliable deployment process. Our app is strictly in AWS. Are there any other benefits for us to use docker?

Answer (score 0):

the Docker image is portable and complete executable of your application: it delivers your jar, but it can also include property files, static resources, etc... You package everything you need and deploy to AWS, but you could decide also to deploy the same image on other platforms (or locally).

Another benefit is the image contains the whole runtime (OS, jdk) so you dont rely on what AWS provides ensuring also isolation from the underlying infrastructure.

Comment: Have you come across any helpful links that explain this in more detail?